# Как разбить файл на несколько других в Python?

Tags: python, файлы

К примеру, есть картинка, нужно разбить ее на 3 части.
Пробовал просто переписать файл - не открывается.

```
clone = open("1.jpg", "rb").readlines()

with open("clone.jpg", "wb") as file:
    file.write(str(b"".join(clone)).encode())
```

Как это правильно реализовать? При чем нужно чтобы скрипт так же умел собирать файл из этих кусочков.

Comment: Что значит "разбить на 3 куска"? Почему в коде Вы просто копируете файл?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов , то и значит. Нужно разбить один файл на три других.
Пробовал хотя бы просто переписать файл.

Comment: Ок. Тогда заменяете `readlines` на `read`, получаете весь файл в переменной `clone`. В первый файл пишете первый байт исходного файла, во второй файл второй байт, в третий файл всё оставшееся.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов , спасибо, помогло.
Не подскажите, как вывести только определенное количество байтов?

Comment: Что значит вывести? Куда вывести?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов , print

Comment: Почитайте про срезы (slice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так.

```
file = open("1.jpg", "rb").read()
with open("clone.jpg", "wb") as part:
    part.write(file)
```

Разделение на куски можно реализовать с помощью срезов ([:]), далее запись каждого куска.